# How to add a style.css to my application through the scene builder in JavaFX?

Tags: java, css, javafx

I am trying to add style.css to my java application in intellij. So I have added a new directory named resources and put the style.css inside that folder. Inside my scene builder I have specified in the GridPane that IO want the file "style.css" in my resources to control the view. However, whenever I run the code I get this error.

**Error:**

```
Oct 29, 2018 3:56:58 PM com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheetUnPrivileged
INFO: Could not find stylesheet: file:/C:/Users/Troy22/Desktop/Java/EMCGrabExtension/out/production/resources/style.css
```

I tried different ways, but non have seemed to help. Thanks again for your help

**Code:**

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,770,450);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("style.css");
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Firstly, *clean* and rebuild your project. Secondly, show us the codes you used to add the css..

Comment: @Jai I provided the code that I am using to access the "style.css" file. I also added the "style.css" file into my fxml as an attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Try Adding it like this in your Main:

```
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
```

Comment: I tried using that code. However,when I add it to my Main class nothing changes.

Comment: Confirm that the file exists in that directory "file:/C:/Users/Troy22/Desktop/Java/EMCGrabExtension/out/production/resources/style.css"

Comment: Hey, I added the code that I am using to access the "style.css" file. Also, I confirmed that the "style.css" file is located in the folder that the compiler says it not. P.S I added the "style.css" in my fxml as an attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding it through scenebuilder (On the top hierarchy node, so if your root node is a BorderPane than add it on this node):

[image: scene builder stylesheet]

However I would recommend adding it like the comment before mine with:

```java
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
```

Don't forget the `.toExternalForm()` after the `getResource()` method.
And be sure your resource folder is in the classpath so Java will find it.