# Where i can find the CSS file after using scene builder?

Tags: css, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm using scene builder to work on my database project, I used the style to add CSS code, but i want the CSS file, where i can find the file so i can attach it to my intelij project then edit the code.

Comment: As far as I know, _Scene Builder_ does not create CSS files. If you were setting CSS via _Scene Builder_ then my guess is you were configuring the `style` property. That property is for adding inline CSS. If you check the FXML file you should see `style="..."` attributes.

Comment: This might help

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53052978/how-to-add-a-style-css-to-my-application-through-the-scene-builder-in-javafx

Answer (score 0):

First Select the component you want to set css,

then it is in the Right sidebar Properties => Stylesheets => '+'.

[image]